# Why is the stem of my ZZ Plant drying?

Tags: diagnosis, houseplants

Why is the stem of my ZZ Plant drying? It was fat like the other stems. Is it dying or doing something for its own good?

I am not overwatering the plant.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is out on your balcony, Yes?  Well, you have got some critter eating this guy.  Just get some chicken wire to protect it.  Do you take it inside for the winter?  Do you even have a winter in India where you need to worry about freezing?  Since you've got a balcony garden I would guess RATS.

The taller stem has an older harvesting and your plant knows that stem without leaves needs to go.  I'd cut it back to 1/4" above that bud angling the cut to shed water off behind the bud.  I don't see the bud on the second shorter stem but do cut that back as well at least an inch angling the cut away so the cut drains water toward the center of this plant.  Forget the littlest one for now.

Have you noticed any other damage on your plants?

Comment: No other damage. Will the plant sprout from these cuttings? Also, is it a slow or fast grower? I haven't noticed any progress since the day I got it.

Comment: Slow grower. It'll put out new stems once or twice a year. I think that's daylength driven, but it's fond of warm temps. Looks like it could use a slightly bigger pot for new growth. Be careful when trans-potting though, it doesn't like having its roots disturbed much. I split a big one once, and it took a year before the parts showed new growth. Despite being dry tolerant, ZZ likes its water.

Comment: Slow grower and that is why it works indoors...VERY slow growth.  Please transplant into potting soil and a new clay pot (wider is better than taller).  Choose a pot not much bigger than what it is already using.  Water fairly deeply and always allow to dry before watering again, go easy on fertilizer, no water left in the saucer.  I'd also use bottled water if you have city tap water.

Comment: It would be fun to try to propagate this plant.  No harm in trying.  But you HAVE TO USE POTTING soil to do so.  Sorry!!  Grins.  Dang, I would love to send you a bag of decent good ole potting soil...and I've recently learned that rooting chemicals are not necessary and sometimes contraindicated.  Water shallowly when trying to propagate and  keep the soil moist not wet.  No fertilizer until later!